# nodeJS mongoose how to make a special get crud

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

That's my mongodb data base shown in cmd as you see there is a field named test which exist a time and one other time didn't exist I want to write  a get method to find field which contain only imei without test

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    Post.find()
        .then((posts) => {
            res.json(posts);
            console.log(posts);
            console.log("ok" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + req.body.imei);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Here the get method it show me all data base I want to customize it.

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6b927e1c2916320ab28de"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "50"
            },
            "test" : {
                    "batterieState" : "0"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6bbbc09183a3e4c833ebe"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "xx"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6bbcb09183a3e4c833ebf"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : ""
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6bc7809183a3e4c833ec0"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "865566048694354"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6bcc309183a3e4c833ec1"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "865566048694354"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6bd1209183a3e4c833ec2"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "865566048694354"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6bdc609183a3e4c833ec3"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "865566048694354"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6be4609183a3e4c833ec4"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "xx"
            },
            "test" : {
                    "tactileState" : "0",
                    "pixelState" : "0",
                    "greyState" : "0"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6be6609183a3e4c833ec5"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "865566048694354"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6beef09183a3e4c833ec6"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "xx"
            },
            "test" : {
                    "tactileState" : "0",
                    "pixelState" : "0",
                    "greyState" : "0"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6bf8709183a3e4c833ec7"),
            "imei" : {
                    "name" : "865566048694354"
            },
            "test" : {
                    "tactileState" : "ignore",
                    "pixelState" : "ignore",
                    "greyState" : "ignore"
            },
            "__v" : 0
    }
```

I want some help for this to write this method correctly to get only fields with imei only and without test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query

```
Post.find({
  imei: {
    $exists: true
  },
  test: {
    $exists: false
  }
})
```

[Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) of `$exists` operator